# In JHipster v6.4.1, where can I put new roles to be authorized to access their account-settings?

Tags: jhipster, roles

While my test user with ROLE_ROOT is allowed to see and configure the Administration tasks and can change password or see the correct response body with a GET to api/account within the swagger-API, he is not allowed to see the components 'settings', 'password' or 'sessions' but gets an `Error Page! You are not authorized to access this page.` via the Angular navbar menu entries.

In fact, I added other roles (ROLE_RUNNER, ROLE_ORGANIZER, ROLE_ROOT) as part of an exercise on udemy. I changed most of the authority of ROLE_ADMIN to ROLE_ROOT. ROLE_ROOT isn't allowed to see or change Entities and ROLE_ADMIN can't do (nor see) any of the Administration tasks.

Also I added ROLE_RUNNER. Like with ROLE_USER their members aren't allowed to see or access anything in the backend as well as the frontend - except 'home' and their 'account'-menue.

But somehow, only ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER, the default JHipster roles, are able to access the 'account'-Spring REST-Controller mappings via the Angular navbar. Where do I have to tell Spring to also let members of the new roles see and edit their account-settings?

The code can be found here: https://github.com/Mesqualito/rfb-loyalty/commit/d3ad5bf3a6a7b0d9926bdcdf99302399faebaf63

Comment: Does the issue appear when accessing front-end routes, or requesting backend API endpoints?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to come back - I fought hours after updating the IDE on a different client. IDEA-gradle-nvm is a bad combination. Now I can tell that the problem is system-independent: it's not possible with users from any new role to get to any of the components in the 'account'-menu via links from the navbar. E.g. if I click on Account>Settings,  the app displays 'http://localhost:9000/accessdenied'. The only nav-link that works in 'Account' is 'Sign out'.
- if I log in and enter 'http://localhost:9000/api/account', I get the acount info for this user displayed in json.

Comment: Does the user have the `ROLE_USER` authority?  If not, they will be denied access to the settings page based on the `authorities` array in `settings.route.ts` https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/8927cdb90782cb76e7e586a75ffb07496569977c/src/main/webapp/app/account/settings/settings.route.ts#L10

Comment: Solved it! Thank you a lot! I was blind and only thinking the error page points me to a lack of authorisation regarding the backend!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For JHipster with Angular frontend the authorisation mechanism follows this pattern:

**1.) Spring backend**

a.) limit access to entities completely in 'SecurityConfiguration.java', e.g. `.antMatchers("/api/customers").hasAuthority(AuthorityConstants.SELLER)` based on user-groups (ROLEs) from 'AuthoritiesConstants.java'

b.) limit access only to all, some or one of the Create/Update/Delete-methods in Controller-Resources with these ROLEs and Spring *Secured* annotations, e.g. in 'UserResource.java'

```
    @GetMapping("/users/authorities")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole(\"" + AuthoritiesConstants.ROOT + "\")")
    public List<String> getAuthorities() {...}
```

c.) limit access to user-data based on user-login at the backend's service layer, e.g. in 'ProductOrderServiceImpl.java'

```
    public Page<ProductOrder> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        if (SecurityUtils.isCurrentUserInRole(AuthoritiesConstants.SELLER))
            { return productOrderRepository.findAll(pageable); }
            else {
              return productOrderRepository.findAllByCustomerUserLogin(
                  SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().get(), pageable );
             }
```

**2.) Angular frontend**

a.) at the Angular routing level for every component with the same ROLEs, e.g. in 'settings.route.ts' with `authorities: ['ROLE_USER','ROLE_ORGANIZER','ROLE_ROOT','ROLE_RUNNER']`

b.) per JHipster-directive `*jhiHasAnyAuthority` in any html-Element with the ROLEs from above, e.g. in 'navbar.component.html'

```
    <a *jhiHasAnyAuthority="['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_ORGANIZER']"
    id="entity-menu">Entities</a>
```

The browser-console shows a `401 (Unauthorized)`, no matter if Spring or Angular rejects the users (or "non-user" `ROLE_ANONYMOUS`) authorisation.