# Remove authorization from JHipster-generated application

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-security, jhipster

I am generating an app(frontend and backend) using the console command: *jhipster*. The app was generated with authorization. Then I was asked to completely remove the authorization.
I found that it is possible to generate a new application with the command: *--skip-user-management*, how to remove authorization for existing application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it, using anonymous user.

1. In SecurityConfiguration.class set permitAll() for all requests and remove beforeFilter().
2. In private-route.tsx set true for checkAuthorities() method.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59212698/7773582 to understand how to remove authorization in an existing application. This is the case for Angular-frontend, I unfortunately don't know where authorization is handled in reactjs as frontend.